# SQL After Insert Trigger - Insert values from Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, triggers

In my database I have one table which when there is a record inserted into it a trigger will use information from the data inserted, run a select statement on the rest of the database, and insert the result into another database on the same server.

Ive never written a trigger before and Im not entirely sure that the examples out there help a lot.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This does not show any research effort or provide any details about what is expected.

Comment: Try this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx Make sure you don't add scalar variables in your trigger. It should be set based and it should utilize at least one of the two virtual tables (inserted and deleted)

Comment: Thanks Sean, apologies for the vagueness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its always good to start learning ...here is some sample code and some links to start ..

```
create trigger <<give your triggername>>
on 
<<give your tablename>>
after insert
as 
begin

select * from inserted--gives me data inserted

--run on rest of database--your logic goes here
select * from inserted i
join
some table tbl
on 
tbl.id=i.id

insert into anotherdatabase.dbo.anotherdatabasetable
select * from inserted

end
```

Also please be aware that ,if the above trigger fails due to some reason ,your insert also will be rolled back..
some good links:
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i
[Insert Update trigger how to determine if insert or update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741414/insert-update-trigger-how-to-determine-if-insert-or-update)
[sql server trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651806/sql-server-trigger)

Comment: Thanks for all the help :-)